# Constructing non-torsion rational points (over Q) on elliptic curves of rank > 1

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Consider an elliptic curve $E$ defined over $\mathbb Q$. Assume that the rank of $E(\mathbb Q)$ is $\geq2$. (Assume the Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture if needed, so that analytic rank $=$ algebraic rank.) How do you construct a point of infinite order on $E(\mathbb Q)$?

(If the rank were $1$, then the Gross-Zagier construction would do the job. If the rank were $0$, then, of course, there would be no such point.)

Implicit in a paper of Mazur and Swinnerton-Dyer ("Arithmetic of Weil curves", Invent. Math., 25, 1-61 (1974); see especially section 2.4) there is a construction that seems to work a positive proportion of the time, though not always. Here is what the construction would be according to my understanding: take a modular parametrisation $\phi:X_0(N)\to E(\mathbb C)$, consider its points of ramification on the imaginary axis (there is at least one), take the image $\phi(z)$ of one such point $z$; due to standard magic, $X_0(N)$ has an algebraic model that makes phi into an algebraic map; the trace of $\phi(z)$ is a point of $E(\mathbb Q)$ that *might* be non-torsion, and sometimes is).

Has any further work been done on this? (In particular, has it been proven that this works infinitely often?) Are there any other constructions for which similar statements have been conjectured or proven?

Harald

Comment: I don't know of any further work on this; my impression is that this construction has been to some extent neglected.

Comment: This article http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/JTNB/JTNB_2005__17_1/JTNB_2005__17_1_109_0/JTNB_2005__17_1_109_0.pdf by Christophe Delaunay talks about this construction. 

Comment: @Chris: And Delaunay concludes that for the rank 2 curve 389a, "the subgroup $E(\mathbf{Q})^{\rm crit}$ is a torsion group" (i.e., 0). 

Comment: @Helfgott: Section 5.2 of [Mazur-Swinnerton-Dyer] discusses another related construction.  This turns out to be related to recent research of Zhang and his students: see  http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/distinguished-lecture-series-iii-shou-wu-zhang-%E2%80%9Ctriple-l-series-and-effective-mordell-conjecture%E2%80%9D/ and  http://www.math.columbia.edu/~yxy/ preprints/triple.pdf    Their triple product L-function result explains why this construction must give torsion points when the analytic rank is 2 or higher. 

Comment: The second link got mangled.  It is  http://www.math.columbia.edu/~yxy/preprints/triple.pdf

Comment: Given William's comment, can you (Harald) be more precise about the statement "construction that seems to work a positive proportion of the time"? I was just independently thinking about this. Somehow I always regarded it as a key unsolved problem---when the rank is bigger than 1 then Heegner points don't work and what have you got left?---but I do remember the M-SD comment. I guess at the time they were hoping that one *might* be able to build points with ease using modular curves. I guess this didn't turn out to be the case but I never thought about "how badly it failed"...

Comment: Kevin - I suppose it would be satisfying if the (first) Mazur-Swinnerton-Dyer construction were shown to work for a positive proportion of all a<=N, b<=N such that y^2=x^3+ax+b is of rank>1, say. One might alternatively hope for a neat characterisation of all elliptic curves for which the construction works (i.e. gives a rational non-torsion point).

Comment: What I meant was: could it be that for *any* curve of rank greater than one, the critical points only give torsion points? You're asking "could it work for a positive proportion" and I'm asking "does it definitely sometimes work?"

Comment: I was certainly under the impression that it did, but now I am having a hard time tracing any source that says it ever does. Exploring this sounds like a very worthwhile computational project (unless somebody can prove the method never works for rank>1 first!).

Comment: @Helfgott: I'm certainly interested in helping with this computational project...

Comment: @Stein: Cool. Let's take this over to email. (Kevin B., are you in?)

Comment: Has there been any recent progress on this very interesting set of questions?

Comment: Not that I know of :(.

Comment: Here is some (fairly) recent progress: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2016-85-301/S0025-5718-2015-03057-9/S0025-5718-2015-03057-9.pdf