# Tunnel like theorem: is there an interesting function with fourier coefficients related to $L'(E_n,1)$ instead of $L(E_n,1)$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Tunnel's result on the congruent number problem hinges on the fact that there are modular forms with fourier coefficients related to the values $L(E_n,1)$.

Is there an interesting function that has coefficients related to $L'(E_n,1)$ instead? (for a reasonable definition of "interesting" and "related")

This is interesting since it can potentially strengthen the solution to the congruent number problem - it might give an effective algorithm to decide if rank$(E_n)>1$ (which is a step before actually constructing the points, as asked in ["constructing non-torsion points ..."](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55423/constructing-non-torsion-rational-points-over-q-on-elliptic-curves-of-rank-1)).

(of course BSD is assumed, along with any other interesting and related conjectures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Bruinier and Ono have shown in their paper "Heegner divisors, L-functions and harmonic weak Maass forms" that the vanishing or nonvanishing of central derivatives of twisted L-functions like this is related to the algebraicity properties of coefficients of a certain harmonic weak Maass form.  You should also look at the classic paper of Gross-Kohnen-Zagier, and the recent paper of Darmon-Tornaria "Stark-Heegner points and the Shimura correspondence", for results of a similar flavor.