# Does the number of roots of the modular form associated to an elliptic curve, on the positive imaginary axis, equal the analytic rank?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, l-functions

Recently I've been playing around with elliptic curves and have seemingly come up with a conjecture that I could not find elsewhere:

> Let $E$ be an elliptic curve, and $f(q)$ its associated modular form. Is it known whether along the positive imaginary axis, the number of roots of $f(q)$ is equal to the order of $L(E,1)$, i.e. the analytic rank?

I've checked a few cases on LMFDB, and the plots of $f\left(e^{-2\pi x}\right)$ along $x>0$ seem to show the same number of roots as the analytic rank of the L-function (or equivalently the algebraic rank of the elliptic curve assuming BSD). One requires several thousand terms of the q-expansion when the conductor is large to have sufficient convergence for all roots to appear. I am curious to know if this has been conjectured before (say as part of the Langlands program) or if it is a known result, or perhaps is actually false?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The elliptic curve $E = 990.e2$ (Cremona label $990b1$) has rank $0$, and the number of zeros of the associated newform $f$ on the imaginary axis seems to be 2 (numerically). Here is some PARI/GP code to plot $y \mapsto f(iy)$ on an interval $[y_1,y_2]$ for a given elliptic curve:

```
{
graph(E, y1, y2) = 
my(e = ellinit(E), [mf, f, v] = mffromell(e));
print("Analytic rank: ", ellanalyticrank(e)[1]);
ploth(y = y1, y2, real(mfeval(mf,f,I*y)));
}

graph("990b1", .01, 2)
graph("990b1", .0001, .01)
```

I found this curve randomly, so there may be examples with smaller conductor.

Comment: Thanks for finding this counterexample- I guess I didn't search far enough. My follow-up question is whether there is perhaps something special in common between these counterexamples that makes their modular forms have more roots on the imaginary axis.

Comment: Interesting question, it would be worth to investigate if this has something to do with the fine behaviour of the Fourier coefficients of $f$.

Answer (score 13):

Let $Z$ be the number of zeroes of $y\mapsto f(iy)$ for $0<y<\infty$ and let $r$ be the analytic rank of $E$. Then $Z\geqslant r$ and $Z\equiv r \pmod{2}$ as I will explain below. I don't know of an example when $Z\neq r$ but also no reason to believe they do not exist.

Let $g(y) = 2\pi \int_{\infty}^y f(i\,t)dt$. Then $g(0) = L(f,1)$ and your zeroes are the stationary points $g'(y)=0$. Mazur and Swinnerton-Dyer call your zeros the fundamental critical point in section 2.4 in "The arithmetic of Weil curves". [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55423/constructing-non-torsion-rational-points-over-q-on-elliptic-curves-of-rank-1) is about them.

If $L(f,1)=0$, i.e., the analytic rank is positive, then $g$ has to have at least one maximum. Instead if $L(f,1)\neq 0$, then it may well be that $g$ has no stationary point and $g$ is a decreasing function. Your function also satisfies $f(i\,t) = \varepsilon\cdot f(i\, t/N)$ where $N$ is the conductor and the root number $\varepsilon$ is $1$ if the analytic rank is even and $-1$ if it is odd.
For odd analytic rank we must have a zero at $t=1/\sqrt{N}$. In general this tells us that $Z$ has the same parity as $r$.
Further Mazur and Swinnerton-Dyer show that the number of zeroes of odd order is at least the analytic rank.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had realised the things mentioned in your last paragraph, except the result of Mazur and Swinnerton-Dyer which is interesting. I decided to not remark on the parity considerations in my question in case it wasn’t particularly relevant. I think it would be interesting if there is an explicit example where $Z\neq r$.